# Canasta pick up from discard pile

Tags: canasta

If your discard is the only card in the discard pile, can the next player pick up the one club assuming they have 2 in their hand.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

Unless the discard was a three or a wild card.  Those can never be picked up when they are on top of the pile.

http://www.canasta.net/canasta_rules.php